# Mastodon toots data collection for privacy and security

Tags: python, security, privacy, mastodon

How we can collect the toot from mastodon from a specific server? Is this possible using python? if not can you give a reason for that. I am glad if you give the answer soon as I have to submit my project review tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it is. By using the APIs. I found this with 15 seconds of googling. https://docs.joinmastodon.org/client/public/#toots

Comment: Can you just tell me how i can use above link format in python or can you provid some link for that?

Comment: The [`requests` library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is popular. `print(requests.get('https://mastodon.example/api/v1/timelines/public').json())` would be the simplest beginning.